# Why thymeleaf <intput type="hidden"> does not work?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm creating a simple Spring Boot application that displays the db tables on the web page.Currently I'm stuck at making CRUD operations for the first table, particulary the Edit operation. I created three html files which are the templates:
index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to My Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <h1>Welcome to my Application!</h1>
    <a class="h2" th:href="@{/states}">Manage States</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

states.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to My Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div><h2>Manage States</h2></div>
    <div class="m-2">
        <a class="h3" th:href="@{/states/new}">Add New State</a>
    </div>
    <div th:if="${message}" class="alert alert-success">
        [[${message}]]
    </div>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Official State Name</th>
                <th>Official Language</th>
                <th>State Currency</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <th:block th:each="state : ${listStates}">
                <tr>
                    <td>[[${state.idState}]]</td>
                    <td>[[${state.officialStateName}]]</td>
                    <td>[[${state.officialLanguage}]]</td>
                    <td>[[${state.stateCurrency}]]</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="h4 mr-3" th:href="@{'/states/edit/' +${state.idState}}">Edit</a>
                        <a class="h4" th:href="@{'/states/delete/' +${state.idState}}">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </th:block>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

states_form.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>[[${pageTitle}]]</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-center"><h2>[[${pageTitle}]]</h2></div>

    <form th:action="@{/states/save}" method="post" th:object="${state}"
        style="max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{idState}">
        <div class="border border-secondary rounded p-3">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Official State Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{officialStateName}" class="form-control" required minlength="4" maxlength="40"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Official Language</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{officialLanguage}" class="form-control" required minlength="4" maxlength="40"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">State Currency</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{stateCurrency}" class="form-control" required minlength="4" maxlength="40"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-2">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary m-2" onclick="cancelForm()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cancelForm(){
        window.location = "[[@{/states}]]"
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a POJO class named State:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "state")
public class State implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_state")
private Integer idState;

@Column(name = "official_state_name")
private String officialStateName;

@Column(name = "official_language")
private String officialLanguage;

@Column(name = "state_currency")
private String stateCurrency;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "state_war",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id_state", referencedColumnName = "id_state",
                        nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id_war", referencedColumnName = "id_war",
                        nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private Set<War> wars = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "state_event",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id_state", referencedColumnName = "id_state",
                        nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id_event", referencedColumnName = "id_event",
                        nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "state_capital",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id_state", referencedColumnName = "id_state",
                        nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id_capital", referencedColumnName = "id_capital",
                        nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private Set<Capital> capitals = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "state", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Figure> figures;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "state", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Governor> governors;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "state", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Statistics> statistics;

public Integer getIdState() {return this.idState;}

public String getOfficialStateName() {
    return this.officialStateName;
}

public void setOfficialStateName(String officialStateName) {
    this.officialStateName = officialStateName;
}

public String getOfficialLanguage() {
    return this.officialLanguage;
}

public void setOfficialLanguage(String officialLanguage) {
    this.officialLanguage = officialLanguage;
}

public String getStateCurrency() {
    return this.stateCurrency;
}

public void setStateCurrency(String stateCurrency) {
    this.stateCurrency = stateCurrency;
}
}
```

And Spring boot components:

Repository:

```
import com.historicalreferencebook.historicalreferencebook.domain.State;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface StateRepository extends CrudRepository<State, Integer> {
}
```

Service:

```
   import com.historicalreferencebook.historicalreferencebook.domain.State;
   import 
  com.historicalreferencebook.historicalreferencebook.exceptions.StateNotFoundException;
import com.historicalreferencebook.historicalreferencebook.repository.StateRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class StateService {
@Autowired
private StateRepository stateRepository;

public List<State> findAll(){
    return (List<State>) stateRepository.findAll();
}

public void save(State state) {
    stateRepository.save(state);
}

public State get(Integer id) throws StateNotFoundException {
    Optional<State> result= stateRepository.findById(id);
    if(result.isPresent()){
        System.out.println(id);
        return result.get();
    }
    throw new StateNotFoundException("Could not find any state with id" + id);
}
}
```

Main contoller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class MainController {

@GetMapping("")
public String showHomePage(){
    return "index";
}
}
```

State controller:

```
import com.historicalreferencebook.historicalreferencebook.domain.State;
import 
com.historicalreferencebook.historicalreferencebook.exceptions.StateNotFoundException;
import com.historicalreferencebook.historicalreferencebook.service.StateService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class StateController {

@Autowired
private StateService service;

@GetMapping("/states")
public String showAllStates(Model model){
    List<State>  listStates = service.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("listStates", listStates);
    return "states";
}

@GetMapping("/states/new")
public String showNewForm(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("state", new State());
    model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "Add New State");
    return "state_form";
}

@PostMapping("/states/save")
public String saveState (State state, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    service.save(state);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "The state has been saved successfully!");
    return "redirect:/states";
}

@GetMapping("/states/edit/{id}")
public String showEditForm(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    try {
        State state = service.get(id);
        model.addAttribute("state", state);
        model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "Edit State (ID: " + id + ")");
        return "state_form";
    } catch (StateNotFoundException e) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "The state has been saved successfully!");
        return "redirect:/states";
    }
}
}
```

This is how the web page looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoXPr.png)

So i did not actually made delete button work, but my problem is, when i try to edit the existing state the db creates a new entity instead of editing the existing one.
When trying to edit:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTWFR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4YCk.png)

It should replace the content of the field "State Currency" but instead it generates a new "Poland". I'm guessing it must be something to do with the idState that I'm missing in the

```html
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{idState}">
```

As the database I use PostgreSQL.
Bootstrap version 4.3.1

Comment: My guess is that you don't have a setIdState function in the model entity which results in the controller being unable to fill said field on post. You could probably check this by inspecting the element in debug mode

Comment: Thanks!!! I missed that, now it works as it should be